# AWS lambda logs stop appearing after some time in Cloudwatch

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have lambda function that fires when a file is uploaded to S3 (it will archive it).
It works great, I could see fresh logs in Cloudwatch... for some time. After a few days no new logs appear.
And the function still works fine because I can see new archives in S3 after the file is uploaded.

When I check the list of Cloudwatch log groups, there is no new group.
If I delete the old group - the new one won't show up (the lambda still works fine).
The only way I was able to see the log again was to **redeploy** the lambda function (without any change), but that is bad solution.

template.yaml :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Some service name

Parameters:
  ENVIRONMENT:
    Type: String
  AccessRole:
    Type: String

Resources:
  archiveS3Files:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/file/archiveS3Files.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Role: !Ref AccessRole
      MemorySize: 3000
      Timeout: 900
      Environment:
        Variables:
          ENVIRONMENT: !Ref ENVIRONMENT
      Events:
        UploadFileEvent:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref Bucket name
            Events:
              - 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: S3Archiver
                  - Name: suffix
                    Value: _startArchiving.json
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one log group per function, but there should be multiple log streams per log group.